# How to Check Current RestKit Version

Tags: ios, restkit

I inherited an iOS project at work and am getting the feeling that it's using an older version of RestKit. Where can I check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After getting more familiar with *how* RestKit is actually linked to the project, where the files live at, etc, I stumbled across the answer:

- Browse to the location of your xCode project containing RestKit
- Open or cd into the RestKit folder
- Open VERSION in vim or other text editor and the version number will be listed there

I guess I was being pretty naive as to the location of the RestKit files. Should've checked there for version info first.

Answer (score 1):

In my version of RestKit (latest as of Feb 20, 2013), the file under the xcode workspace folder with the version info in it is named "RestKit.podspec" (I installed RestKit with CocoaPods). Here is what to look for at the top of the file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name         =  'RestKit'
    s.version      =  '0.20.0rc1'
    ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CocoaPods, just run `pod install` and you will get a printout with the following information.

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (1.3.3)
Using RestKit (0.20.3)
Using SOCKit (1.1)
Using TransitionKit (1.1.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```